# How do I convert a numpy array filled with strings to json

Tags: python, arrays, json, numpy, encode

```
n=int(input('n='))    
array = np.empty(shape= 
[n,4],dtype='|S10')
.
.
.
.
array= array.tolist()
array =[[b'1',b'1/1/1',b'1',b'1']]
dump(array,json_file)
```

I got an error: **Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable**

Comment: `n` is not defined and `[[b'1', b'1/1/1', b'1', b'1']]` is a list and not an array (so `array` is a list). The assignment in Python does not copy the content (it just set a reference).

Comment: n is an input from the user (number of rows)

Comment: array= array.tolist()

Comment: are this comments part of the code? if so, edit your question instead of writing comments.

Comment: why 'S10'?  why not 'U10'?  Or even an `astype` change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you type 'b' before the strings ?

Your code is not complete, I modified it to let it work:

```
import numpy as np
import json

n=int(input('n=')) 
array = np.empty(shape=[n,4],dtype='|S10')
array = [['1', '1/1/1', '1', '1']]
with open('test.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(array, json_file)
```

That if you want your current code to work, if you want to serialize a numpy array of strings you must use 'U1' dtype and then convert it to list, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import json

n = int(input('n=')) 
array = np.empty(shape=[n,4], dtype='U1')
array = array.tolist()
with open('test.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(array, json_file)
```

Comment: i dont type b its automatically because its of type bytes the issue is that i cant convert bytes to json for example '1' raises an error but "1" doesnt

Comment: I edited the answer check it.

Comment: as i said this error comes out **Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable**

Comment: array = np.empty(shape=[n,4],dtype='S')
array[0,0]='1'

Comment: could not convert string to float: 'test'

Comment: I edited my answer check it, use 'U1' dtype instead of 'S'

Comment: thx it solved it

Comment: Welcome my pleasure, please accept the answer